# How do I change directory for UltiSnips snippets?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-ultisnips

What is the correct way to change where UltiSnips searches for snippets? I tried the lines below with no success:

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir = "/newfolder/snippets/"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnipsNewDir"]
```

Comment: Have you read the corresponding doc at `:h UltiSnips-snippet-search-path`? It precises that your directory `UltiSnipsNewDir` must be a sub directory of one of them defined in `runtimepath`, is your new directory placed in the right place?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what setting `g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir` actually does either UltiSnip's documentation is misleading or this is a bug. However, adding your directory to `rtp` by itself does what you want.

```
set rtp+=/newfolder/snippets
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnipsNewDir"]
```